# Javascript forEach executes content only for last value

Tags: javascript, foreach

Im trying to change style on an element by its id that is stored in an array. I want the process to run on every element in the array but it only runs one time on the last element. The elementid constant is supposed to be that way.
This is the code:

```
    const hideTiles = (ids, hideTileset) => {
    const elementid = '${elementId} === ';
    ids.forEach((id) => {
      hideTileset.style = new Cesium.Cesium3DTileStyle({
        show: {
          conditions: [
            [elementid + id, false],
            [true, true]
          ]
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: well, you do set `hideTileset.style` in each iteration, so only the last will be the current "style" - it's like saying `a = id` in the forEach ... `a` will end up being the last `id` - since `a` (or in this case `hideTileset.style`) can only be one value

Comment: Of course, thank you @Bravo